# Safari page scrolling is stuck at bottom of scrollable div

Tags: javascript, html, css, safari

I have a weird issue only in the Safari browser with scrolling on a blog page on my site.

The page in question: https://www.forliving.co/blog/spring-2021-gift-ideas-simple-sustainable-presents

**Desired functionality**: When the user scrolls through the post content on the right side and gets to the end of the scrollable div, I'd like the scroll-down action to scroll down the whole page down to see the related articles below the post. It works exactly as expected in Chrome.

In Safari, when I attempt to scroll down on the article content (using the touchpad on my MacBook Pro), I get a jittery shaking of the article and the page stays in place. However, if I scroll quickly and let go of the touchpad the page will jitter for a second and then scroll down - almost like it's responding to the 'momentum' of the scroll, but not to the scrolling directly.

**I just want it to work in Safari like it does in Chrome!
Any ideas?**

Comment: I've had the same issue, searched around, and concluded it's a bug with Safari. Not much you can do here :/

Comment: @User10 how annoying! I'm glad I'm not alone at least...